# BLEACH_DEFAULT_WIDGET django

Tags: django, tinymce, bleach

I have django-bleach in my  project.
In models use:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_2 = HTMLField()
```

In settings.py:

```
BLEACH_DEFAULT_WIDGET = 'wysiwyg.widgets.WysiwygWidget'
```

How to write the correct path to process the bleach for **HTMLField** in **BLEACH_DEFAULT_WIDGET**  ?

Comment: Why not use `BleachField` on the model?

Comment: 'cause that's the task, we use tinyMCE htmlfield. Maybe we i tryuse bleachfield and inherit TinyMCE i new model?

Comment: BLEACH_DEFAULT_WIDGET = 'tinymce.widgets.TinyMCE' didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think what you're saying is you need bleach to use the TinyMCE widget in your form.

(Assuming you're using [django-tinymce](https://pypi.org/project/django-tinymce/))

The setting would be `BLEACH_DEFAULT_WIDGET = 'tinymce.widgets.TinyMCE'`

Because you're using `HTMLField` on the model you'll need to define a form for your model that then uses `BleachField` in order for bleach to be involved.

```py
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    content_2 = BleachField(
        max_length=100,
        strip_tags=True,
        allowed_tags=[]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

Comment: @SergeyKa excellent news. Can you mark it as accepted so it's clear the question has been answered?